# CSS height:auto doesn't work with my wrapper div

Tags: html, css

I was hoping someone can take a look at my site and tell me what may be going on here. The problem I'm having is that the #bodyWrap div is not automatically stretching to the height of one of it's children, #contentWrap. #contentWrap stretches fine to fill all the content on that page, but this does not bubble up to the parent, #bodyWrap. Thanks in advance for any insight.

http://www.jacobsmits.com/placeholderRX/index.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You must add a *clearer div* before your closing containers:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

**Floating items won't affect the height of the container**...coz it is floating ;).

Working Live Example : http://jsfiddle.net/LBH5h/

**Example :**

```
<div id="content">
  <!-- floating child --> <div style="float:left;"><!-- floating child content --></div>

  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I always use a "clear" class when I know i'm gonna float elements but I missed it when i was experimenting and just couldn't see the problem this late haha. Is there a way to get a floating element, such as that navwrap, to stretch to the bottom of the page though? Check the site again to see what I mean.

Comment: I'm gonna probably end up using Javascript to set the navWrap height to the contentWrap height. Much easier than wrestling with absolute positioned Divs and Z-indices.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to get time and check it now.. working on a deadline. But an easy way is to include the navwrap image to your tiling content background. ;) Otherwise I think you'll have to change html structure and play around with css display:table options. OR read the height of content with jQuery... and set the navwrap to similar..you can even pop in an animation ;) cheers buddy

Comment: NP! I just did it with .outerHeight(). Two lines of jquery saves me an hour of CSS wrestling :)

Comment: +1 Thank you man. That's a vital important rule - "Floating items won't effect the height of the container".

Answer (score 4):

If something usually won't auto adjust the height for me then I will troubleshoot with these steps.

1. Set the height to something ridiculous (1000px)
2. If that make a difference then check all floats
3. Add a clear:both; statement.
4. If it's still not working, add separate border colors to all of your divs. It should help you out to see whats setting the height properly and whats messing up the website.

Comment: Same thing happened to me today, it was because there was a `display: absolute` in the wrapper, I changed it to `relative` and it worked.