# My css height auto doesn't work

Tags: html, css, css-float, less

Sorry if my post title duplicate because I can't find solution for my problem on other topics. I don't know why height css doesn't with my div. It makes me crazy. Hope someone can help me out. Thank in advance.

[Here my code at Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fHzwh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the buttons' `float: left` setting into `display: inline-block`

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yvpGm)

Comment: thank for supporting, but in this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516875/css-heightauto-doesnt-work-with-my-wrapper-div they said "Floating items won't effect the height of the container". Is it right?

Comment: It's true. They're not effecting their container and therefore they just float outside of it.

Comment: but why in my case, you change float to display:inline - block, bro?

Comment: That way it's not floating and it actually taking the required place in the container and stretch it.

Comment: thank you. Can you give me advice when use ul with display or float?

Comment: Most of the time `inline-block` display will do everything `float` can do and behave more logically.